# Is there any tips for minimising access to a public page without login?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, non-interactive

I have a page that is just a non interactive display for a shop window.

Obviously, I don't link to it, and I'd also like to avoid people stumbling across it (by Google etc).

It will always be powered by Chrome.

I have thought of...

- Checking User Agent for Chrome
- Ensuring resolution is 1920 x 1080 (not that useful as it is a client side check)
- Banning under robots.txt to keep Google out of it

Do you have any more suggestions?

Should I not really worry about it?

Comment: You should just make it authenticated via the web-servers auth system, then have it accessible only by logging in. Inevitably, you'll want to track users anyway, you I'd do that.

Comment: If you dont link to it, and it is a single page. Why must it be public? What is the requirement for making it public?  Couldnt you just host it locally/internally?

Comment: It's tied to a public website. This is my first time I've done something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I would EVER recommend what I'm about to suggest - how about filtering by IP address. Since you provider IP is rarely going to change you can use Javascript to kick out or deny requests from IP addresses other than yours. Maybe a clean redirect to http://www.google.com or something silly like that. Although I would still suggest locking it down with a login and password and just have it write a never expiring cookie. That's still not a great idea but a shy bit better than the road your trucking down right now.

Comment: No, stick with your first instinct and don't suggest this. It's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could always limit the connections by IP address (If you know it ahead of time/it's reliable):

[Apache's access control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for a shop window, do you even need access to a web page?

You can host the file locally.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it, if no-one is linking to it externally it is unlikely to ever be found by search engines.

Comment: It needs to access things from the Internet, and I'd like to be able to easily push changes.

Comment: I would just let it sit on the internet, just dont link to it from anywhere.